# Python: replace a column from a dataframe based on another column from another dataframe over an index column

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, replace, merge

I have a dataframe DF1:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 121 | 1313 | + | 102466751 |
| 2 | 112 | 133 | + | 6147 |
| 3 | 122 | 313 | - | 55207 |
| 4 | 212 | 413 | - | 113655 |
| 5 | 1012 | 343 | + | 79501 |

and another dataframe DF2"

| no | Ensmbl | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1212 | ENSG00000146083 | 22838 |
| 1512 | ENSG00000198242 | 6147 |
| 1262 | ENSG00000134108 | 55207 |
| 1219 | ENSG00000167700 | 113655 |
| 1512 | ENSG00000070087 | 521 |

I am trying to get on the following final Dataframe DF3 in which it will look like:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 121 | 1313 | + | 102466751 |
| 2 | 112 | 133 | + | ENSG00000198242 |
| 3 | 122 | 313 | - | ENSG00000134108 |
| 4 | 212 | 413 | - | ENSG00000167700 |
| 5 | 1012 | 343 | + | 521 |

where the DF3 contains on the DF2.ensembl if and only if DF1.ID == DF2.ID otherwise DF1.ID remains with no changes.

I wrote in Python:

`DF3['ID'] = DF1['ID'].apply(lambda x: DF2['Ensembl'] if DF1['ID'] == DF2['ID'] else DF1['ID'])`

Value Error was:

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge into `df1` and then replace ID with non-NaN values from Ensmbl column.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="ID", how="left")
m = ~df3["Ensmbl"].isna()

df3.loc[m, "ID"] = df3.loc[m, "Ensmbl"]
print(df3[df1.columns])
```

Prints:

```
   1     2     3  4               ID
0  1   121  1313  +        102466751
1  2   112   133  +  ENSG00000198242
2  3   122   313  -  ENSG00000134108
3  4   212   413  -  ENSG00000167700
4  5  1012   343  +            79501
```

Note: I'm assuming the last ID is 79501 and not 521 (probably a typo.)